# Factory Boy FuzzySubFactory available?

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am wondering if there is something like FuzzyChoice for Objects.

Background is that I have a base factory and 3 different implementations.
Another Factory which uses these factories should randomly choose one of the three implementations. So I did not found that specify FuzzySubFactory within the docs but is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks and regards
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define a list with the desired factories and the use python buidl-in `random.choice(items)`.